# Number type states value is undefined yet won't let me set the value as undefined later

Tags: typescript, types

I have a defined Type that contains a set of optional number props and a function type that expects number args.

I am using `useState` to establish a variable and setter with the initial value being that of the object type defined.

The issue I'm seeing is that I'm seeing multiple red squiggled in my IDE when I am **(1)** trying to use this variable's values and **(2)** when I am trying to set the object's key values to `undefined`...

```
type PropTypes = {
    dimensions: {length: number, height: number, width: number};
    onRecordDimensions: (h: number, l: number, w: number) => void;
    ...
};

...

const MyComponent = (props: PropTypes) => {
    const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState(props.dimensions);

    ...
    if (someCondition) {
        props.onRecordDimensions(dimensions.length, dimensions.width, dimensions.height);
        /*
            Each of the dimensions.xxx I get red squiggles stating:
 
            Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.   
            Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'
        */
    } else {
        props.onRecordDimensions(undefined, undefined, undefined);
        /*
            Under each undefined I get red squiggles stating:

            Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'
        */
    }
}
```

I did come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73257422/why-wont-typescript-allow-me-to-set-undefined-when-it-is-allowed-to-set-it) that suggested adding `"strict": true` to the tsconfig.json `compilerOptions`, however this didn't seem to work, even after a restart of my IDE.

I know that I can 'get around' the issue by adding a `?` and `!` to my usage (ie. `dimensions?.length!`) to tell the code that this will always have a value, and null check it, but this feels like it defeats the purpose of stating the keys are optional in the initial `Type` declaration...

I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Please provide a playground with the `someCondition`. I'm not sure where undefined is coming from

Comment: Please [edit] to make your code into a [mre] others can paste into their own IDEs to see the problem you're seeing.  Also, does this question depend on third-party frameworks like react?  If so then you should consider tagging it as such; if not, please remove the apparent dependency from your example code.  Good luck!